# How to create object in Kotlin without getting "Null can not be a value of a non-null type Long"?

Tags: kotlin, jvm

I am totally new in Kotlin as a former Java guy and try to understand some errors.

I am getting a record from db (Postgres) by using JpaRepository. I want to create a new record but the new record will only have 2 different value in its fields and I want to add it (***not updating the previous one, instead adding new one***)

```
val otp = notificationRepository.findById(id).get()
        val newOtp = otp
        newOtp.delivery = newOtp.delivery.plusMinutes(OTP_RESEND_TIME_IN_MINUTES);
        newOtp.status = NotifyStatus.PENDING
        newOtp.id = null // HERE I AM GETTING ERROR
        //save logic here
```

I cannot set id of the new record to null to save it because the ide giving error "*Null can not be a value of a non-null type Long*"

How can I create a new object by just updating some fields and making 'id' null to store it ?

Comment: Do you really need the `id` field to be null? Obviously that depends on your save logic; but if that will be assigning a new ID anyway, then presumably you don't need to clear it first. Or if it _won't_ automatically assign a new ID, then how do you tell it to? If that's by setting it to null first, then you'll have to make the field nullable as Saeed shows.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you should define your class:

```
class Notification(
    val id: Long?,
    val status: NotifyStatus,
    val delivery: DateTime
)
```

As i did not know what the class look like, i guess you must have a class or data class look like it.

if you want declare a variable nullable you should use `?` after its type.